# Questions about $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{p}]$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I studied this part where they talk about $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ and I really start to get confused.

*Definitions:*
$$
\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] = \left\{ a + b \sqrt{2} \mid a,b \in \Bbb{Q} \right\} \\
\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \left\{ \tfrac{a + b \sqrt{2}}{c + d \sqrt{2}} {\Large \mid} a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{Q} \text{ and } (c, d) \ne (0, 0) \right\}
$$

I have a few questions that I might not be able to prove, but I'll provide my intuition.

---

**(Q1)** Is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ ring or group isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$?

**(Q2)** Is $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ ring or group isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$?

**(Q3)** Find order of $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})(\sqrt{q}): \Bbb{Q}]$.

**(Q4)** Is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})(\sqrt{q}) = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$?

I think **(Q1)** is not ring isomorphic. When they say group isomorphism in a field, I don't know whether we consider the additive group or multiplicative as $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a field.

**(Q2)** Not ring, but group isomorphic (considering addition)

**(Q3)** 4?

**(Q4)** Yes.

Please enlighten me on this. I am confused.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No, I am preparing for an entrance exam. These all questions came to my mind.

Comment: @user141561: the mind that produce these question should solve also ;:)

Comment: For future reference, "some questions that confuse me" is an awful title. Please try to pick something that will help other people who might be looking for the same question. I've already edited it to be a little better, and I hope it suits you. It can always be changed again if  you wish. Regards

Comment: Haha. I might have seen them somewhere while studying or on the internet.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thank you. I was eager to write the questions before i forgot, so didn't pay heed to the title. Sorry.

Comment: I don't see the difference between $Q[\sqrt{2}]$ and $Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: I edited your question to make the math markup clearer (hopefully).  Have a look and make sure that it still faithfully represents your questions.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/472506/589.

Answer (score 10):

**Fact:** $\mathbb Q(a)=\mathbb Q[a]$ if $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

The reason is consequnces of the lemma:

**Lemma** $\mathbb Q(a)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ which spanned by $1,a,a^2,..,a^n$ where $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

Now, Let $\phi:\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)\to \mathbb Q(\sqrt3)$ be a nontrivial ring homomorphism.

Notice that $\phi(1)=1$ so if $2=\phi(2)=\phi(\sqrt2 )^2 \implies \phi(\sqrt2)=+-\sqrt 2$ which is not in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3)$

But  they are isomorphic as a group as both of them has $2$ dimension over same field space.

**Q3:** $|\mathbb Q(\sqrt p ,\sqrt q):\mathbb Q|=|\mathbb Q(\sqrt p ,\sqrt q):\mathbb Q(\sqrt p)||\mathbb Q(\sqrt p): \mathbb Q|$ and we have $|\mathbb Q(\sqrt p): \mathbb Q|=2$ and $|\mathbb Q(\sqrt p ,\sqrt q):\mathbb Q(\sqrt p)|\leq 2$
 but notice that it can not be $1$ which means that they are equal which is not the case if $p,q$ are different prime. Since both of them $2$, answer is $4$.

**Q4:** It is clear that $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt p +\sqrt q) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\sqrt p ,\sqrt q)=K$ And let's assume that L is a proper field of $K$. Since $|K:\mathbb Q|=4$ then we must have $|L:\mathbb Q| =2$ but it means that $\sqrt p +\sqrt q$ is a root of second degree polynomial $x^2+bx+c$ from there you can easily reach contradiction.

Comment: You do need to justify why $\sqrt{2} \not \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ (which is not difficult: check that $(a+b\sqrt{3})^{2} \neq 2$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I had left it to OP, but you solved it :)

Comment: So (Q($\sqrt2$, +) $\cong$ (Q($\sqrt3$, +) as groups?

Comment: @user157116: yeah you are right.

Answer (score 5):

First of all $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}] \cong \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$, as rings.  The latter notation is meant to suggest that these rings are, in fact, fields.  Every nonzero element is a unit.  It all boils down to this identity:
$$
(c + d \sqrt{p})(c - d \sqrt{p}) = c^2 - pd^2 \in \Bbb{Q}.
$$
This allows any *rational expression* in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ to be written in a form that shows its membership in $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}]$:
$$
\frac{a + b\sqrt{p}}{c + d\sqrt{p}} = \frac{(a + b\sqrt{p})(c - d\sqrt{p})}{(c + d\sqrt{p})(c - d\sqrt{p})} = \left( \frac{ac - pbd}{c^2 - pd^2} \right) + \left( \frac{bc - ad}{c^2 - pd^2} \right) \sqrt{p} \in \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}],
$$
provided that the only solution to $c^2 - pd^2 = 0$ is the trivial one $(c, d) = (0, 0)$.

---

Does this help?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not write $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}] = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$?  I would claim that they are equal, not just isomorphic.

Comment: Fair enough, @SpamIAm.  The map providing the isomorphism is the identity.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

1) No, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \not\cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. Any ring homomorphism between them will fix $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\mapsto\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is some ring homomorphism. We will require $\varphi(\sqrt{2})=a+b\sqrt{3}$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Carrying on with this, we will find $2 = \varphi(2) = \varphi(\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2})= \ldots = a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt{3} \not\in\mathbb{Q}$ which is a contradiction.

3) and 4). There is a need to be careful here, unless $p$ and $q$ are definitely prime (which you haven't specified). The reason is that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{b})$ if there is a $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a = c^2b$. Other than this case, I think you're right.

Comment: I don't see a (straightforward) justification for your claim that we must have $\phi(\sqrt{2}) = \pm \sqrt{3}.$

Comment: I disagree. Yes, $\phi$ has to be injective and $\phi$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}.$ But what is the justification for saying that $\phi(\sqrt{2} \neq a + b \sqrt{3}$ for any non-zero $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}?$ It is true, but needs some proof.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that.. I'm apparently getting complacent.