# For rings $R \subseteq S, \alpha \in S,$ how is $R(\alpha)$ defined if $\alpha$ has no inverse?

Tags: ring-theory

I understand that $R(\alpha)$ is defined to be the smallest subfield of $S$ that contains $R$ and $\alpha.$ But how is it defined if $\alpha$ has no inverse for example?

Comment: It usually isn't defined.  Where have you seen this notation?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472497/field-extension-notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not defined.  The notation $R(\alpha)$ is normally used only when $R$ and $S$ are fields.  It may also be used sometimes where $S$ is only an integral domain, in which case it refers to the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $R$ and $\alpha$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $S$.